# Java Package Not Found: Compiling with CPlex from command line

Tags: java, command-line, compiler-errors, cplex

I'm trying to compile a java project which uses CPlex from the command line. The command I'm currently trying is

`javac -cp "opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/cplex/lib/cplex.jar" *.java`

I get about 98 errors, which I believe are all stemming from the first one:

```
error: package ilog.concert does not exist
```

I believe that it can't find the CPlex package I'm trying to include. I'm 100% sure that the "/opt" directory I used above is where CPlex is installed. Please let me know what I should try!

EDIT: This is the gist of what's in my cplex.jar file, according to vim:

```
     zip.vim version v27
" Browsing zipfile /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/cplex/lib/cplex.jar
" Select a file with cursor and press ENTER

META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ilog/concert/IloAddable.class
ilog/concert/IloAnd.class
ilog/concert/IloColumnArray.class
ilog/concert/IloColumnArray$Link.class
ilog/concert/IloColumnArray$SizeMismatchException.class
ilog/concert/IloColumn.class
ilog/concert/IloColumn$Link.class
ilog/concert/IloConstraint.class
ilog/concert/IloConversion.class
ilog/concert/IloCopyable.class
ilog/concert/IloCopyManager$Check.class
ilog/concert/IloCopyManager.class
ilog/concert/IloCopyManager$ExistFreeTerm.class
ilog/concert/IloCopyManager$ExistGroundTerm.class
ilog/concert/IloException.class
ilog/concert/IloIntCollectionVar.class
ilog/concert/IloIntExpr.class
ilog/concert/IloIntSet.class
ilog/concert/IloIntSetVar.class
ilog/concert/IloIntToIntFunction.class
ilog/concert/IloIntToNumFunction.class
...
```

Comment: Where is your ilog.concert package?

Comment: @Top.Deck Not really sure now that you ask. I thought the cplex.jar file was supposed to give it to me. When I search in that file there is no mention of the ilog.concert package. Should I expect to find it there?

Comment: The easiest way to see what the correct command line arguments are is to use the `Makefile` that comes with the examples. For example, `cd /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/cplex/VERSION/PLATFORM` (where `VERSION/PLATFORM` is, for example, on Linux, `x86-64_linux/static_pic`). Then, simply run `make execute_java 2>&1 | tee output.txt`. This will compile all of the java examples, execute them, and store the output in output.txt. Then, you can open output.txt in a text editor to see what the command line arguments that you should be using are.

Comment: @rkersh maybe I am misunderstanding something...what is the "execute_java" part of the command I should run? When I go to the static_pic directory I see 3 files with a *.a extension - I don't see a makefile.

Comment: I'm sorry, the path I gave above was not quite correct. It should be `/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/cplex/examples/VERSION/PLATFORM`. It sounds like you were looking under `/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/cplex/lib/VERSION/PLATFORM`. The `execute_java` part of the command is just the name of the make target; it just compiles and executes the CPLEX java examples. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command I needed was

`javac -classpath .:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/cplex/lib/cplex.jar *.java`

See the javac documentation for more info: http://www.cs.yorku.ca/tech/other/java/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html (I should have checked this out earlier :O).

The `.:` at the beginning of the path allows me to include my current directory as well.